# Getting error java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-studio

I am learning how to use Linear Layouts. I created a new layout resource file, dragged the buttons and text, adjusted their properties. The app crashes when tried running on virtual device with API 16.
I tried the following solutions but didn't work:

- I've changed the API to 15
- I've changed my app theme to Holo.light.DarkActionBar

Here is the logcat:

```
06-14 20:56:20.692 1281-1281/? D/dalvikvm: Late-enabling CheckJNI
06-14 20:56:20.728 1281-1287/? D/dalvikvm: Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries
06-14 20:56:20.796 1281-1281/? W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Landroid/view/SearchEvent;)
06-14 20:56:20.800 1281-1281/? I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.view.Window$Callback.onSearchRequested, referenced from method android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onSearchRequested
06-14 20:56:20.800 1281-1281/? W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve interface method 18815: Landroid/view/Window$Callback;.onSearchRequested (Landroid/view/SearchEvent;)Z
06-14 20:56:20.800 1281-1281/? D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x72 at 0x0002
06-14 20:56:20.800 1281-1281/? I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.view.Window$Callback.onWindowStartingActionMode, referenced from method android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onWindowStartingActionMode
06-14 20:56:20.800 1281-1281/? W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve interface method 18819: Landroid/view/Window$Callback;.onWindowStartingActionMode (Landroid/view/ActionMode$Callback;I)Landroid/view/ActionMode;
06-14 20:56:20.800 1281-1281/? D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x72 at 0x0002
06-14 20:56:20.816 1281-1281/? D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
06-14 20:56:20.816 1281-1281/? W/dalvikvm: threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xa6253288)
06-14 20:56:20.816 1281-1281/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-14 20:56:20.816 1281-1281/? E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.shubhendu.linearlayoutexperiments/com.example.shubhendu.linearlayoutexperiments.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-14 20:56:20.816 1281-1281/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2059)
06-14 20:56:20.816 1281-1281/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
06-14 20:56:20.816 1281-1281/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
06-14 20:56:20.816 1281-1281/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
06-14 20:56:20.816 1281-1281/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-14 20:56:20.816 1281-1281/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-14 20:56:20.816 1281-1281/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
06-14 20:56:20.816 1281-1281/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-14 20:56:20.816 1281-1281/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-14 20:56:20.816 1281-1281/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
06-14 20:56:20.816 1281-1281/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
06-14 20:56:20.816 1281-1281/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-14 20:56:20.816 1281-1281/? E/AndroidRuntime:  Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-14 20:56:20.816 1281-1281/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.example.shubhendu.linearlayoutexperiments.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:22)
06-14 20:56:20.816 1281-1281/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
06-14 20:56:20.816 1281-1281/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
06-14 20:56:20.816 1281-1281/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)
06-14 20:56:20.816 1281-1281/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084) 
06-14 20:56:20.816 1281-1281/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130) 
06-14 20:56:20.816 1281-1281/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195) 
06-14 20:56:20.816 1281-1281/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
06-14 20:56:20.816 1281-1281/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
06-14 20:56:20.816 1281-1281/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745) 
06-14 20:56:20.816 1281-1281/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
06-14 20:56:20.816 1281-1281/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
06-14 20:56:20.816 1281-1281/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786) 
06-14 20:56:20.816 1281-1281/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553) 
06-14 20:56:20.816 1281-1281/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
06-14 20:56:22.640 1281-1281/? I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 1281 SIG: 9
```

My MainActivity.java :

```
package com.example.shubhendu.linearlayoutexperiments;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.linear_experiment);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

And my linear_experiment.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_weight=".5"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="New Button"
            android:id="@+id/button" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="New Button"
            android:id="@+id/button2" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_weight="0.5">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="New Text"
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="New Text"
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="New Text"
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Seems like this line : `fab.setOnClickListener` causes the error. Which means the `fab` is null. Can you check if it's id is correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
```

There is nothing in your layout that is a `Toolbar` or has `android:id="@+id/toolbar"`.

```
FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
```

There is nothing in your layout that is a `FloatingActionButton` or has `android:id="@+id/fab"`.

Comment: nice spot. It's probably legacy code from using a template.

Comment: Surely. You're not even using it. It's what you had left from auto-generated template.

Comment: @Shubhendu: Presumably, yes. More importantly, you need to determine why you had them in the first place. If Vucko is correct, and you are trying to modify code that was generated by a template, you need to be consistent about what you are changing. You might wish to work from an up-to-date book or online training course to learn what these things are and how to get started with Android.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you don't have a button that is named "fab". You need to change whichever button you are trying to use with that name to this.
 android:id="@+id/fab" />